# XCUItest system alert

Tags: cucumber, xctest, xctestcase, xcuitest

I am trying to automate my App using XCUITest and Cucumberish, I'm not able to Click system alert such as permission as Location and Contact but am not able to Click "Allow" or "OK", it's clicking "Don't Allow" or "Allow" Arbitrarily".

This is my Code which I am trying to use in my step definition:

```swift
systemAlertMonitorToken = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons.matching(identifier: "Allow").count > 0 {
      alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
      return true
    }
    else if alert.buttons.matching(identifier: "OK").count > 0{
      alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
      return true
    }
    else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's currently hard to tell what is a button label and what is part of the functionality in your question. Could you use quotes around labels to better explain? And in the above case, a screenshot may help understand the problem better.

Comment: Try using the same query for your if statement as inside your if statement (using `["Allow"]` instead of `matching(identifier:)`)

Answer (score 4):

I use this code to tap permission screens in my app:

```swift
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
            
let allowBtn = springboard.buttons[identifier]
            
if allowBtn.waitForExistence(timeout: 4) {
    allowBtn.tap()
}
```

Where `[identifier]` would be "Allow" or "Don't Allow" or whatever option you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's an issue with using matching(identifier: "Allow").count. Perhaps Xcode thinks both the "Dont Allow" and "Allow" buttons are the same XCUIElement.

If you know "Allow" and "Ok" buttons will always be at the same boundBy position, you can tap the button by the position. I would just check for the button's existence, then tap the button based on it's boundBy number.

For example, if the alert has 2 buttons, the left button says "Allow" and the right button says "Dont Allow" the code would look like:

```
systemAlertMonitorToken = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
    if alert.buttons["Allow"].exists || alert.buttons["OK"].exists {
        alert.buttons.element(boundBy: 1).tap()
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```